# How do I use jquery to modify or remove a single options from a select?

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have the following displaying in a modal

```
<select id="orgUsers" multiple="multiple" value="Users" style="min-width:200px">    <option 
     value="info@compliancecare.us">info@mail.us</option>    <option 
     value="test@compliancecare.us">test@mail.us</option>    <option 
     value="Marko@compliancecare.us">Marko@mail.us</option> 
</select>
```

Trying to modify the option for 'info@mail.us using:

`$('#orgUsers option[value="info@mail.us"]').css({"display":"none"})`

If I select the whole select it works. but I can't seem to select just one option.

Comment: You can't hide an `<option>` cross browser. Some don't support it. Choices are disable/enable or remove/replace

Comment: Also note the value you are using in jQuery selector matches the text of the option but not the `value` attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is fine but the value in the selector matches the option text not the `value` attribute.

Beyond that you can't hide an `<option>` in all browsers, some don't support it

```js
$('#orgUsers option[value="info@compliancecare.us"]').css({"color":"red"})
                           // ^^^ actual option value
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="orgUsers" multiple="multiple" value="Users" style="min-width:200px" size="6">    <option 
     value="info@compliancecare.us">info@mail.us</option>    <option 
     value="test@compliancecare.us">test@mail.us</option>    <option 
     value="Marko@compliancecare.us">Marko@mail.us</option> 
</select>
```